Light turning right back on after giving command in Arduino
I am using a serial prompter (the message system) on my Arduino but the command (sensor loop) defaults to off if I don't explicitly tell it to turn on and I'm trying to figure out how to default it to on then only if I turn it off will it go off.
Here's the code I tried
String command = "on";
int ledPin = 13;
int sensorPin = 4;
bool val = 0;
int currentValue;
int previousValue;

void sensor(){
  val = digitalRead(sensorPin);
  if (val < HIGH){
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
    else{
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      delay(1000);
    }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Available! Give command ('on' or 'off').");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()){
    command = Serial.readString();
    command.trim();
    command.toLowerCase();
    Serial.println(command);
    if(command.equals("on")){
      sensor();
    }
    else if(command.equals("off")){
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
  }
}

Any help would be appreciated!
